# delegate click event on document

Tags: javascript, beginner, event-handling

I'm adding an onclick listener to the whole document then checking the source of the click. If the source of the click contains the attribute `data-widget` I want to go to the appropriate action. I did it but I'm hoping for a more efficient way of doing things and if I can do without the self invoking function.

```
<div data-widget="myaction"> Click here </div>

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var widgets = new Widgets();
    var w = e.target.getAttribute("data-widget");
    if(w){
        e.preventDefault();
        widgets[w];
    }
});

function Widgets(){
    var myaction = (function myaction(){
        console.log('indeed');
    })();
}
```

Comment: The `widgets[w]` line does nothing but access a member of that object. It doesn't appear to call a function. Is that the intent?

Comment: @GregBurghardt reading the variable evaluates the lambda and executes it.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Pimgd: No it doesn't. The "myaction" variable is just that - a local variable to the `Widgets` constructor and not publically available using dot or array syntax. Invoking `new Widgets` is actually calling the "myaction" function. This is a bug since the "data-widget" attribute does not even need to exist to execute that function.

Comment: @Pimgd It's sad because I received an answer that I think I would have benefited more if my edit was available, as I think what he does is close to what I had in my edit. I feel like opening a new question would polute the forum

Comment: That's because Code Review StackExchange doesn't focus on the asker & answerer but it focuses on the content instead. The idea that you can type into google your question and find a relevant answer. When you "update" your question to contain the code after fixes, someone who comes here from google can no longer see what the reviewer is pointing at. Plus, if reviewers start reviewing the updated code... then the answers become a mess.

Comment: @Pimgd I agree with you and don't really want to argue about it but I feel as my question was faulty to begin with because it contained an error as other pointed in their answers

Comment: @Ced It happens... we (as a community, on meta) have decided that it's better to leave it broken and have the question + comments + answers make sense rather than leave everything in a mess. That's why we promote follow up questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For readability, place space characters around the parenthesis in `if` statements:

   ```
       if (condition) {
   ```

   Instead of:

   ```
       if(condition){
   ```
2. The line of code:

   ```
       if(w) {
           widgets[w];
   ```

   Doesn't actually do anything. It accesses a property and nothing more. To invoke a function, maybe you want:

   ```
       // Pass in the event object in case someone needs it
       widgets[w](e);
   ```
3. Creating a new `Widgets` object on each click can be a tad wasteful. Since they are so disposable, create one instance and hide it from the global context using an auto invoked function expression:

   ```
       (function(widgets) {
           document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
               var w = e.target.getAttribute("data-widget");

               if (w) {
                   e.preventDefault();
                   widgets[w](e);
               }
           });
       })(new Widgets());
   ```
4. This also necessitates changes to the `Widgets` class:

   ```
       function Widgets() {
       }

       Widgets.prototype = {
           constructor: Widgets,

           myAction: function(event) {
               // do stuff
           },

           anotherAction: function(event) {
               // do more stuff
           }
       };
   ```
5. You don't need to attach the handler to the `document` object. You have a couple of options:

   1. Attach it to the `document.body` object. This works well because "click" events sure can't from the `<head>` element. The disadvantage is that you must wait for the `<body>` element to exist before attaching the event handler
   2. Attach event handlers to `document.documentElement` which is the `<html>` tag. Yes, the event must bubble up *two* whole more DOM nodes than it needs to, but this property exists as soon as JavaScript begins executing. No need to wait for the "DOM ready" event. Just attach the handler and be on your merry way.
6. Consider removing the call to `e.preventDefault()` and let the widget methods decide to do that. This way you can respond to an event, but not change its default behavior.

You've got the right idea. It's a pretty good attempt at a simple event delegation framework. Clean and concise.

Answer (score 2):

The way constructors work is that the engine creates an object, and calls the constructor passing the object as context. Essentially, the constructor is being run *like a function*.

`console.log('indeed');` runs because you created an instance of `Widget`, which *calls the constructor* and runs your iife. The following code alone works in the same way.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var widgets = new Widgets();
});

function Widgets(){
  console.log('indeed');
}
```

Now your code creates a `Widgets` instance regardless of the presence of `data-widget`. If you only deal business when it has `data-widget`, I suggest you create the instance within the if block.

I'm not sure what your goal with `widgets[w]` is, but if you mean storing `w`'s value as a property of an instance of `Widgets`, I it's best if you define the object's properties in the constructor in advance. While this sacrifices dynamicity, it eliminates guesswork as to what properties an instance of `Widgets` contain.

Additionally, delegating all the way up to `document` is slow. That's one reason jQuery deprecated [`live`](https://api.jquery.com/live/) and provided you [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) instead. `live` bound all handlers to `document`, while `on` gives you flexibility to where you want the delegate target bound.

Comment: The `live` method in jQuery queried the document every so many seconds to update collections of DOM nodes. The `on` method *is* the very same event delegation posted in the question. The only difference is you can call the `on` function using any element. Adding the event listener on the `document` object is not nearly as slow as you say.

Comment: @GregBurghardt http://www.sitepoint.com/on-vs-live-review/

Comment: My intent with widgets[w] is to call a function with the same name as my attribute so I don't have a switch inside my condition. About your last paragraph I've read some questions on SO where the answers basically said it could be slow. However I've quite an huge amount of click events with a comment section similar to reddit's. I checked the source of reddit and as far as I can tell they use delegation all the way to document. I didn't notice huge delays when using their website.

Comment: Could you give me a codified example for what you'd do for widgets ? Basically I wanted to have my functions for widgets being encapsulated there and call them on the fly depending on the value of the argument data-widget. I marked it as answered as you have reviewed my question already, further insight would be appreciated though

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer: Correct. But under the hood, the `live` jQuery method is polling the document with the given selector to attach event handlers directly to the DOM nodes, vs. `on` which utilizes event delegation, albeit closer to the event target element than using the `document` element.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Interesting. Where in the jQuery source can I see `.live` polling the DOM?

Comment: @Ced Asking for code is off topic. We only review what you have, and since what you have isn't really that much, we don't know where you're actually going.

Comment: And of course now I can't find the actual JavaScript code to back up my statement from before. :) Retracted.